# Import Error with certain modules in pyoptsparse

Tags: python-2.7, openmdao

Hello everyone,

I have installed Openmdao, pyOpt and pyoptsparse on my computer. As my program works with the Scipy optimizer, I tried it with a random optimizer of pyoptsparse (that was 'ALPSO'). It worked and I was happy. But it turns out it seems to be the only one working.

Every time I try to use another one (like 'SLSQP', which is the default optimizer !), i get this message "pyOptSparse Error : There was an error importing the compiled SLSQP module", inside a frame made of '-' and '+'.

Does anybody know what to do ? I am using Ubuntu if it changes something.

Comment: Can you provide a few more details, like which version of OpenMDAO you're using, what method you used to install, and which version of Ubuntu you're using?

Comment: @kmarsteller
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with the 1.6.4 version of openmdao. I used pip to install openmdao, and i have taken from bitbucket the repository of pyoptsparse, and then i runned from the repository : python setup.py install

Comment: Hmmm. It sounds like your installation versions/method are correct.  And OpenMDAO can see pyoptsparse, or ALPSO wouldn't work, I assume.  Can you post some code that is generating the errors?

Comment: Here is an example taken from the paraboloid tutorial :
Choice = 1 uses Scipy, Choice = 2 uses pyOpt with ALPSO and i get that : "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison if 'coo' in mat:", but it gives a correct answer. Choice = 3 uses pyOpt with SLSQP and i get : "pyOptSparse Error: There was an error importing the compiled slsqp module", with the last Traceback of Error : [...]/pySLSQP.py, line 77, in __init__ slsqp module') pyoptsparse.pyOpt_error.Error

Comment: Note that when i print _check_import() (from pyoptsparse driver) i get that : ['ALPSO', 'CONMIN', 'FSQP', 'IPOPT', 'NLPQLP', 'NSGA2', 'PSQP', 'SLSQP', 'SNOPT', 'NLPY_AUGLAG'].

Comment: @kmarsteller : for this example i just replaced the line choosing an optimizer by that :
if choice == 1:
        top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
        top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
        top.driver.options['disp'] = False
    else:
        top.driver = pyOptSparseDriver()
        top.driver.options['print_results'] = False
        if choice == 2:
            top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'ALPSO'
        else:
            top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to swryan for the link, i found the answer.

One of the possible answer was to put libgfortran.so.3 in anaconda2/lib, but i already had it.

They were also saying the problem was solved when installing anaconda 4.0+ but i also had the latest version.

What worked for me was to run : conda update libgfortran --force

Doing it without the --force retrogrades the scipy, which seems to disable scipy.optimize.least_squares. If you did that, you can then run conda update scipy --force

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any errors when you ran 'python setup.py install' for pyoptsparse?  I looked at the setup.py file for pyoptsparse and there are some instructions in there that you could try:

```
    print("\nTo install, run: python setup.py install --user\n\n"
          "To build, run: python setup.py build_ext --inplace\n\n"
          "For help on C-compiler options run: python setup.py build --help-compiler\n\n"
          "For help on Fortran-compiler options run: python setup.py build --help-fcompiler\n\n"
          "To specify a Fortran compiler to use run: python setup.py install --user --fcompiler=<fcompiler name>\n\n"
          "For further help run: python setup.py build --help"
      )
```

Comment: I did not get any errors, but i got several warnings like "unused variable"

Comment: i only ran the install line without building it, could it be the problem ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I built pyoptsparse so I don't remember if I needed to use the --inplace or not.  Which version of python are you using?

Comment: i am using python 2.7 with the latest version of anaconda2

Comment: I created a new anaconda environment using conda 3.18.3 and python 2.7, numpy, scipy, and six,  then ran 'python setup.py install' in the pyoptsparse repo.  I was then able to do 'from pyoptsparse import SLSQP'.  It gives a warning because I didn't install mpy4py, but it imports successfully.

Comment: i can also import SLSQP, that is the problem. Openmdao uses a function that tries every optimization method and returns a list of all those that could be imported. Here is what it gives for me when i print it : ['ALPSO', 'CONMIN', 'FSQP', 'IPOPT', 'NLPQLP', 'NSGA2', 'PSQP', 'SLSQP', 'SNOPT', 'NLPY_AUGLAG']

Comment: Actually, it looks like after you import SLSQP, you need to also instantiate an SLSQP object in order to see the import error you're seeing.   I can instantiate an SLSQP object without any errors in my new anaconda environment.  Unfortunately in the pyoptsparse code, it puts the import in a try..except block and doesn't display the error message.  

Try the following:   'import pyoptsparse.pySLSQP.slsqp' and see what you get.

Comment: here is what i get : ImportError: ../libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /home/gael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyoptsparse/pySLSQP/slsqp.so).

Comment: so for some reason it can't find libgfortran.so.3.  You could maybe try adding the directory that contains libgfortran.so.3, wherever that is on your system, to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  On my system it's in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.   It also appears to be in the lib directory of my anaconda environment, although that's not the one that my slsqp.so links to.

Comment: See this thread, there are a couple of different suggestions there:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/686